# Step by step on how to create a production version in android studio

Tags: android

I'm a new Android developer and I just finished my first app and I want to create the prod version of it. I search in google of course but I still fail to understand the explanation. Please give a easy/understanding steps on how I will create a production (release) version.

Comment: Try https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html - searching with "release" rather than "prod" gives a better set of matches.

Comment: thank you I will try that link

Answer (score 0):

Before you export the .apk file, you need to create your own .keystore file.
[https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html?](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html?hl=ko)

And then In Android Studio, Click Build > Generate Signed APK > Follow the steps with your keystore file.